# Caliburn event not fired

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a simple WPF Control with a button on it that uses caliburn micro event wiring ([caliburn cheat sheet](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet)):

```
<UserControl xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
  <Button Name="Save" Content="Save"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter] = [Action DoSmthg]" />
</UserControl>
```

The user control is integrated to the main view as

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding MyViewModel}" />
```

In the view model I have the corresponding method:

```
public void DoSmthg()
```

When I start my app, the method is not called, so I initial considered that I made a mistake with the wiring. But when I modify the XAML file while debugging (e.g. adding a space), everything works as expected. SO it looks to me, that while startup, the event is overridden by something else, and when I update the XAML the caliburn event is updated again. Since I removed everything that could disturb in my code I have no idea what the reason could be. Any ideas, how I can find the issue?

The issue is independent of the event type. Also happens when I add parameters. And no errors or warnings in output.

Remark: When I add a breakpoint in the OnInitialized(EventArgs e) method of the code behind and execute Message.GetAttach(Save) I can see that the event is set up correctly.

Comment: Can you show more code? The displaying/binding of the user control etc?

Comment: Does the VM do anything when it's instantiated/bound/attached etc?

Comment: No, just creating a dummy ViewModel. I removed as much as possible of the logic for breaking the error down.

Comment: could you show your bootstrapper? and the complete wpf ...?

Comment: I managed to "fix" it: I wrap a stackpanel around the button and add the message.attach on it and it works. I don't understand why...